# Can the Arduino use this i2c LCD Panel

Tags: i2c, lcd

Can the Arduino Mega2560 use the [New Haven NHD-0420D3Z-NSW-BBW-V3](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/nhd0420d3znswbbwv3-p-5745.html) LCD panel by controlling it with the [New LiquidCrystal library](https://bitbucket.org/fmalpartida/new-liquidcrystal)? What cable will you use to connect the LCD to Arduino, are there screw terminals on the LCD board to secure the connections? It seems like only 4 connections are needed, for `GND`, `VCC`, `SDA`, `SCL`.

Comment: The I2C in that library is expecting a IO expander ASIC. The display you use requires different I2C commands. Better look around for a different library.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot control that display using that library; the library expects to be connected to a HD44780-compatible driver but the display uses a fully custom control scheme. You may be able to adapt the library to the scheme, but I have not looked at that specifically.

I<sup>2</sup>C itself only requires 3 connections: SDA, serial data; SCL serial clock; GND, ground reference. Since the display is not powered separately it also requires power, in this case 5V. Since the display can only communicate at 100kHz you don't need to be *too* terribly concerned about cable quality; Cat3 or even telephone cable is acceptable as long as you don't exceed a few feet in length. [Don't forget the external pullup resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102611/what-happens-if-i-omit-the-pullup-resistors-on-i2c-lines) though, on SDA and SCL.